# Bold text with asterisks

Tags: python, django

In my Django project I want to make text bold if asterisks `*` are there at the start and end of text, the same feature we have here on Stack Overflow. Although I convert `**` to `<b>`, due to output escaping it becomes `&lt;b&gt;`. What is the right approach to achieve this?

template file contains `{{ anidea.description|format_text}}`

`format_text` is custom template filter

code..

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='format_text')
def custom_formating(value):
   for word in value.split():    

     start = word[:2]
     end = word[-2:]

     if start == '**' and end == '**':
        word = word[2:-2]        
        word = '<b>' +word+ '</b>'
        mark_safe(word)    


  return value
```

Comment: Could you show a [mcve] of your current implementation? Have you considered using an existing Markdown library? Read up on when and how Django applies HTML escaping?

Comment: "Bold for Delphi is an advanced Object Relational Mapper (ORM) and application framework. Do not use for the font style named "bold"." Please read your tag descriptions when adding them.

Comment: I am new to django.. not much aware about library

Comment: Then *do some research*, follow a tutorial or something. Don't just dump every little road bump on SO.

Comment: I got your point. Markdown library I know. But for some reason i dont want to off `autoescape`

Comment: Please read the whole of jonrsharpe's comment. Create an [mcve].

Comment: plz check updated question

Comment: your call to `mark_safe` does nothing, why can't you just `return mark_safe(value)`? (where value is actually something worth returning)

Comment: @Sayse `return mark_safe(value)` can't do this bcz I don't want to make whole value `safe`. that's why avoiding `{{ anidea.description|safe }}`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am not dumping everything. I did research. It might look a very small thing to you but being a newbie I found it challenging as I want to mark safe only few words in string, not whole string.

Comment: But you showed **none of that** in the first revision.

Comment: @jonrsharpe its ok. I would appreciate if you provide me some solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the full suite of all markdown features, go with an existing markdown library.

if you just want <b> to print directly to the source code w/o escaping, use

```
 {{ some_var|safe }}
```

Comment: I don't want to off `autoescape`

Answer (score 0):

I did it in following way.

views.py

```
i.description = i.description.split()  #use of split()
```

template file (format_text is `custom template filter`)

```
{% for text in anidea.description %}
     {{ text|format_text }}
{% endfor %}
```

filter

```
@register.filter(name='format_text')
def custom_formating(value):
 start = value[:2]
 end = value[-2:]

 if start == '**' and end == '**':
     value = value[2:-2]        
     value = '<b>' +value+ '</b>'
     return mark_safe(value) 
 else:
     return value
```

with this way I can achieve output escaping for description and desired text formatting.